# Error launching Jupyter lab in new environment

Tags: python, installation, error-handling, anaconda, jupyter-lab

After creating a new environment in Anaconda I installed `Jupyter lab` through the navigator. When I try to run, the following error message appears:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\notebookapp.py:73: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
_("Don't open the notebook in a browser after startup.")
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\notebookapp.py:89: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
_("Allow the notebook to be run from root user.")
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\traits.py:20: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
help=_('Deprecated: Use minified JS file or not, mainly use during dev to avoid JS recompilation'),
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\traits.py:25: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
help=_("Supply extra arguments that will be passed to Jinja environment."))
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\traits.py:29: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
help=_("Extra variables to supply to jinja templates when rendering."),
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\traits.py:62: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
help=_("""Path to search for custom.js, css""")
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\traits.py:74: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
help=_("""Extra paths to search for serving jinja templates.
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\traits.py:85: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
help=_("""extra paths to look for Javascript notebook extensions""")
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\traits.py:130: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
help=_("""The MathJax.js configuration file that is to be used.""")
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\traits.py:143: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
help=(_("Dict of Python modules to load as notebook server extensions."
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\notebookapp.py:122: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
description = _("""The Jupyter HTML Notebook.
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\notebookapp.py:143: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
help=_("""Path to search for custom.js, css""")
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\notebookapp.py:155: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
help=_("""extra paths to look for Javascript notebook extensions""")
[I 2022-02-13 18:11:53.842 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2022-02-13 18:11:54.449 ServerApp] 'ExtensionManager' object has no attribute '_extensions'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\Scripts\jupyter-lab-script.py", line 9, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 567, in launch_instance
serverapp = cls.initialize_server(argv=args)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 537, in initialize_server
serverapp.initialize(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 88, in inner
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 2341, in initialize
point = self.extension_manager.extension_points[starter_extension]
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 303, in extension_points
for value in self.extensions.values()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Environment_1\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\nbserver.py", line 80, in extensions
nb = self._extensions.get("nbclassic")
AttributeError: 'ExtensionManager' object has no attribute '_extensions'
```

I've found the same error in some SO questions which all pointed me to this [Github issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10228), which suggests that an updated verison of `nbclassic` should solve it.
I tried to install the latest version (actually it seems it was already installed when creating the environment) but the error persists.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error message attempting to run `jupyter lab` today after updating everything on Anaconda. It did not affect `jupyter notebook`, so that may still work regardless.

What worked for me was running the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge nbclassic=0.2.8
```

Previously I tried the advice of others which had recommended:

```
conda install -c conda-forge nbclassic>=0.2.8
```

It seems that version 0.2.8 works, however the current version (0.3.5) of [nbclassic](https://pypi.org/project/nbclassic/) may be causing the error. Rolling back to 0.2.8 may also work for you.